# Angular - npm install

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

While I delete and install npm for taking build in ionic android I  got this error.

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: events@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1000.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1000.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1102.4" from @ionic/angular-toolkit@3.1.1
npm ERR!   dev @ionic/angular-toolkit@"^3.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Preetha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Preetha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-01T07_15_57_715Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It is actually included in the error message: use npm --force install..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is mentioned in error message, try with:

```
npm i --force
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your packages to the last versions of Angular or at least align them to the `@angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1102.4"`.